# How do I make these fields autopopulate from the database?

Tags: php, html, loops, conditional-statements, repopulation

I have an array, which holds values like this:

```
$items_pool = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 72 [quantity] => 6 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [quantity] => 1 )
[4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 7 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[6] => Array ( [id] => 8 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[7] => Array ( [id] => 9 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[8] => Array ( [id] => 19 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[9] => Array ( [id] => 20 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[10] => Array ( [id] => 22 [quantity] => 1 ) 
[11] => Array ( [id] => 29 [quantity] => 0 ) 
)
```

Next, I have a form that I am trying to populate. It loops through the item database, prints out all the possible items, and checks the ones that are already present in $items_pool.

```
<?php foreach ($items['items_poolpackage']->result() as $item): ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="measure[<?=$item->id?>][checkmark]" value="<?=$item->id?>"> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know what logically I'm trying to accomplish here, but I can't figure out the programming.

What I'm looking for, written loosely is something like this (not real code):

`<input type="checkbox" name="measure[<?=$item->id?>][checkmark]" value="<?=$item->id?>" <?php if ($items_pool['$item->id']) { echo "SELECTED"; } else { }?>>`

Specifically this conditional loop through the array, through all the key values (the ID) and if there's a match, the checkbox is selected.

`<?php if ($items_pool['$item->id']) { echo "SELECTED"; } else { }?>`

I understand from a loop structured like this that it may mean a lot of 'extra' processing.

**TL;DR** - I need to loop within the array, check for the key 'id', then print a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need something like this?

```
array_walk($items_pool, create_function('$array', 'global $item; if( in_array($item->id, $array) ) { echo "checked=\"checked\""; }'));
```

Conside this though, if you stored your products in a single dimensional array (presuming the ids will always be unique

```
$items_pool = array(id, quantity)
```

You will not end up with having duplicated entries of products and can incremement/decrement the quantity easier.

```
$items_pool[id]++; /* or */ $items_pool[id] = $items_pool[id] + 2;
```

Both techniques *should* work if the id exists in the array or not.

If you are hoping to store other attritubes in this array other than quantity, you can

```
$items_pool = array(id=>array(quantity=>3, colour=>"red"));    
$items_pool[id][quantity]--;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper attribute is checked="checked"...

```
if (isset($item_pool[$item->id]) && $item_pool[$item->id] > 0) {
    echo ' checked="checked"';
}
```

Comment: That conditional doesn't post if there's a match. The array isn't labeled true to the ID, it needs to cycle through each array and compare the ID from the item to any ID in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo ($items_pool[$item->id] ? ' checked="checked" ' : ''); ?>
```

Another option would be to use `array_keys` to grab the keys of the selected items and then do something like `in_array($item->id, $item_keys)`. All depends on how you feel like doing the work. The tertiary operators are the easiest way to do what you want to inline. You can also use a simple `if` statement to echo the attribute if you want it.

```
if($items_pool[$item->id]) echo ' checked="checked"';
```